# Java 9 Proxy::getProxyClass Deprecation and ObjectInputStream::resolveProxyClass

Tags: java

`Proxy::getProxyClass` has been deprecated in Java 9.  What is the alternative to its use with regard to custom `ObjectInputStream` objects, when its necessary to override the `resolveProxyClass` method?  It should not be necessary to construct an object using `Proxy::newProxyInstance` as the documentation for `getProxyClass` suggests.  Thank you in advance.